# Jupyter Notebook not working in browser

Tags: windows, localhost, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I downloaded Anaconda and attempted to run Jupyter Notebook right away but the browser tab displays

> This page isn't working, localhost is currently unable to handle this
>   request. HTTP ERROR 500.

I've looked all over online for answers but haven't found any solutions that have worked, so I re-downloaded Anaconda to start over from there. Even putting 'http://localhost:8889/tree?' into the address bar yields the same non-working result. I don't know how to get the Jupyter Notebook to run properly.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Windows and with Anaconda. I had the same problem when trying to run `jupyter notebook` in a new created virtual environment using **python27**. One of the part of the error message said: `TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'urlencode'`. I found the key hint to solve the problem [here](http://simnotes.github.io/blog/installing-jupyter-on-hdp-2.3.2/). It seems that there was a problem related with **Jinja2**. I solved the problem by typing the following in my virtual environment:

```
conda install -c anaconda jinja2
```

I hope it will help